# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException in spring data jpa

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

i have (one to many) and (many to one) bi-directional mappings while i am querying with @Query with spring- data-jpa using repository  using foreign key iam getting InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

```
@Entity(name="docket")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Docket implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)

    @Column(name="docket_Id")
    private long Id;

    @Column(name="docket_name")
    private String docket_name;

    @Column(name="area_in_kms")
    private long area_in_kms;

    @Column(name="number_of_connections")
    private long number_of_connections;

    @Column(name="number_of_sewer_connections")
    private long number_of_sewer_connections;

    @Column(name="number_of_manholes")
    private long number_of_manholes;

    @Column(name="deep_manholes")
    private long deep_manholes;

    @Column(name="contour_low")
    private long contour_low;


    @Column(name="contour_high")
    private long contour_high;


    @Column(name="length_of_sewermain_kms")
    private long length_sewer_in_kms;

    @JsonBackReference(value="section-details")
    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "section_Id")
    private Section section;


@Entity(name="section")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

public class Section implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @Column(name="section_Id")
    private long Id;

    @Column(name="section_name")
    private String section_name;

    @Column(name="area_in_kms")
    private long area_in_kms;

    @Column(name="calculated_length")
    private long calculated_length;

    @Column(name="area_geometry")
    private long area_geometry;

    //@JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "section", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Docket> docket;





@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface DocketRepository extends JpaRepository<Docket, Long>  {


    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)

     @Query(nativeQuery=true,value= "select d from docket d where d.section_id = :section_id" )
    List<Docket> findAlldocketsforsection(@Param("section_id") long id);
```

need help!! on this i need to query more custom queries in this api please suggest me from where i am getting error

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: why are you using `@Modifying` for a query which is not doing any modification. It is just retrieving

Comment: i have removed @Modifying still it is not working

Comment: Please post the updated code and the stack trace.

Comment: This is the error with PostgreSQL privileges and table details from model.class too i have written like this @Entity(name="docket") but it should be  @Entity
@Table(name="docket",schema = "postgres") in thise case and her "postgres" is user name of DB for Association mappings PostgreSQL is fallowing strict mechanism by giving model class it is creating another storage in DB from that path i got privileges to access the data ..

Comment: Exception in my case ??      "could not execute query; SQL [select d from Docket d where d.section_Id = ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query